# Delete browser history

Tags: javascript, browser, browser-history

How to delete browser history? Is there any solution, using JavaScript or anything else?

Comment: We're going to have to know which browser you are using.

Comment: You can delete history by going to the browser's options menu then clicking "Delete History".

Comment: Why do you have to do this programmatically? What's wrong with the function built into the browser specifically for this?

Answer (score 1):

No, this is definitely not possible from JavaScript, as it would be a big security hole - any website you visit could delete your history.

You can do it from the browser UI, or by using a browser plugin, but that depends on the browser.

Maybe you can explain what your problem is, then we may be able to help better.

Comment: Hi All, I have developed one online examination system using ASP.net and C#, in that if first user sign in and finish exam of him and second user logged in on same machine on same browser and same test paper then answer remains in browser history and it is not possible manually each and every time, So please help me.....I am using IE 7.0 and above...

Comment: Your problem should probably be resolved by redesigning your examination system. The page contents should be rendered based on the current session. Sounds as though you have something similar to a static page for the exam answers.

Answer (score 0):

When you go back to the first page in the back button history and then change the url to your desired page, then the browser history gets cleared. This can be achieved with following piece of code.

```
window.history.go(-(window.history.length-1));
window.location.href="http://newUrl";
```